# how do add small disk feature in ARM Template

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I am trying a way to add a 32 GB OS Disk in Azure rather than the 127 and need a way how to implement in arm template. was referring to the DOC : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-smaller-windows-server-iaas-image/
how to add the `-smalldisk` param to the template.
template code snippet for the arm template mentioning the storage profile.

The error being faced is `The specified disk size 32 GB is smaller than the size of the corresponding disk in the VM image: 127 GB.`

```
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[parameters('osdiskname')]",
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('osdiskSize')]",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "[parameters('imagePublisher')]",
                        "offer": "[parameters('imageOffer')]",
                        "sku": "[parameters('imagesku')]",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [
                        {
                            "name": "[parameters('datadiskname')]",
                            "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('datadiskSize')]",
                            "lun": "[parameters('lun')]",
                            "createOption": "Empty",
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: please try to update the value of  `imageReference\sku` as `{..-smalldisk}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create small disk VM, you define`"storageProfile": {"imageReference": "sku": "{vmsku}-smalldisk}}"` in your template. For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-smaller-windows-server-iaas-image/)
[image]

For example (I create Azure windows server 2016 small disk VM)

```
"storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "diskSizeGB": "32",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2016-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                        "version": "latest"
                    }
                },
```

[image]